# Asp.net MVC, after using jeditable (Edit in place)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, i can use jeditable to edit-in-place some content on a page and the content will be saved to a database. But whats the best way to re get that text-content from db to show into a place holder?

```
 p id="paraNo34" class="editable"
    -->What i will write here so that it will get content from a 
       db's table: [Content], where id=="paraNo34".
 /p
```

The problem is if i will use some hard coded text like

```
  p id="paraNo34" class="editable"
    -->Some text here
  /p
```

I will able to edit-in-place using jeditable but when i will refresh page it will show the same "Some text here" as its not getting data from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode implies that you want the view to be responsible for fetching the required data, which is an anti-pattern in MVC. You need to retrieve the text in your controllers action and pass it to the view, either using `ViewData` or a custom view model, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // call some method to fetch data from db
    ViewData["ID"] = id;
    ViewData["Content"] = content;
    return View();
}
```

And the view looks something like:

```
<p id='<%= ViewData["ID"] %>' class="editable">
    <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Content"]) %>
</p>
```

A better approach would be to create a strong-typed view model (Stephen Walther has a blog post about view models [here](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx)), but the above example should illustrate how data can be passed from the controller to the view.